# Iterate Wordpress custom field?

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-fields

I have a custom field in an Apus theme of type multi checkbox and I need to display the selected values. 
I am using this code:

```
  <?php $keywords = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), REALIA_PROPERTY_PREFIX . 'keywords', true ); ?>
    <?php if ( ! empty( $keywords ) ) : ?>
        <li><span><?php echo esc_html__( 'Keywords:', 'apushome' ); ?></span> <?php echo esc_attr( $keywords ); ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What this code is showing is

```
Keywords: Array
```

How can I loop the field's values to show them on the page?

Best regards
Americo

Comment: Yes, because it's array of items .i.e., keywords in your case. Use foreach loop to print keywords individual values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may also use

echo implode(",",$keywords);

maybe this would help if this is indexed array, otherwise use

```
foreach ($keywords as $val){ 
  echo $val. "\n"; 
}
```